# Regarding Queues

Tags: queue, theory

New to stackoverflow but had a quick question about queues. I'm not entirely sure how to phrase the question but here it goes:

Say you had a drive in: there is an order queue and a pickup queue. Normally you go and order + pay at the order queue and then once complete switch to the pickup queue. The average time for a customer to come in is 3 minutes, average time in order queue is 1 minute and average time in pickup que is 1 minute.

In a similar situation, you have an order queue, a pay queue and a pickup queue. Now the average wait time for the order que is half a minute, the average wait time for the pay queue is half a minute and the average wait time for the pickup is still 1 minute, with a average time of 3 minutes for every customer to come into the store.

My questions are:

1) Would you expect the total average wait time for a customer to be higher in case 1 or 2?

2) How would you expect the queues to differ if the average time for a customer to enter the store is increased or decreased?